# Umbraco backend keeps showing loading animation because of iframe

Tags: umbraco

I have a small extension im making for Umbraco, but i have run into an annoying problem. I have a small website i need to show in my backend of Umbraco. So i make my new section, and my new tree. Then in the edit.html file i simply insert the url to my website on my localhost. Everything works as expected, *besides* from the native spinner in umbraco wont stop spinning.

```
<div ng-controller="Netbase.Controller">
    <div>
        <h2>{{Title}}</h2>
        <iframe src="http://localhost:64254/" id="contentPage" style="margin-left:15px;margin-right:15px" width="100%" height="100%" />        
    </div>
</div>
```

However, if i remove my iframe, everything works fine and the spinner is gone. It is umbraco that is showing the spinner.

My Angular controller is empty besides for me setting a title (that works fine).

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question, but maybe this will help someone else. The loading graphic is a background applied to all iframes by the Umbraco CSS. Here's how I handled it.

In the HTML for the iframe include the following attribute:

```
 data-ng-init="iframeLoaded()"
```

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.iframeLoaded = function() {
    $('#contentPage').css('background', 'none');
};
```

Comment: Cheers Tim, a perfect reason why you should always answer a question regardless of age.